# Is it OK to pass member object in base class initialiser list?

Tags: c++, inheritance, initialization, initializer-list

I have two classes where one is a base class containing a pointer to a member object on a derived class.

Like this:

```
class Bar { };

class Foo : Bar { };

class A
{
    public:
         A(Foo *foo) { this->foo = foo };

    private:
        Foo *foo;
}

class B : public A
{
    public:
        B() : A(&bar) { };

    private:
        Bar bar;
}
```

My question is: is `B.bar` *guaranteed* to be allocated *before* being passed as an initialisation parameter to the constructor of `A`?

Put another way: if I create an instance of `B` is `B->foo` guaranteed to be a valid pointer to an instance of a `Bar`?

Comment: Yes, this is perfectly safe, but don't read from or write to the object before the initializer list has completed (that is, don't read from or write to an uninitialized `Bar`).

Comment: It is guaranteed to be allocated but not initialized...so if A does anything with Foo in the constructor your SOL. In general, A having a reference to something it doesn't own is a pretty scary design.

Comment: @MadScienceDreams Re: scary design, this is for an OO wrapper. The reason I am using this pattern is to avoid duplicate code in derived classes. E.g. say `Foo` implements `add()` and `Bar` overrides `add()`, I want an `addWrapper()` on my base class (`A`) which calls the correct `add()` depending on whether it is an instance of `A` (wrapping `Foo`) or `B` (wrapping `Bar`). Can you suggest an alternative pattern that is less scary and still avoids duplicating an `addWrapper()` for every derived class?

Comment: @JamieBullock Not addWrapper, lets make A an abstract class, with `class A{protected:/*could be public*/ virtual Foo& get_foo() = 0; public: virtual /*could be non-virtual*/ void add() { get_foo().add();}` Alot of people prefer to have A be a pure interface, this is a little more dirty: A is an abstract class with only member functions, no members.

Comment: @MadScienceDreams many thanks. that design makes a lot of sense to me and I can see it is cleaner than the one in my question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The base subobject is constructed *before* the member objects. Pointers and references to all the members are valid, but you must not access the actual objects until they are constructed.

Comment: +1 Likewise on destruction. The base class destructor cannot use the object reference/pointer either, as the derived destructor has already sent it to the abyss.

Comment: To be clear, are we saying the order is this: `A` is allocated; `B` is allocated; the default constructor of `B` is called, allocating `Bar`; `A` is initialised via initializer list, `A`'s constructor is called, `B`'s constructor is called?

Comment: @JamieBullock Close...1) A and B are allocated at the same time, including ALL MEMBERS (including Bar). 2) The constructor for B is entered. we begin initializing the members of B in the order in which they were declared. The A parent of B is considered the first member. Any member in the list not explicitly initialized takes the default constructor. 3) As the first member, A is initialized. Just like B, first members are initialized. 4) A's constructor body is called. 5) After A is done, we move to the other members in B. This includes Bar's default constructor. 6) B's constructor body.

Comment: @JamieBullock: Not quite: 1) Storage is obtained for the entire object. 2) The `A`-subobject is initialized with the initializer you specified (causing the matching constructor of `A` to be invoked). 3) The non-static data members of `B` are initialized. 4) The constructor body of `B` is executed.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that while the particular example works (object is allocated so taking addresses of its members works), it is not a universally valid pattern (which I just learned hard way).

There is implicit cast B* to A*, which in this case is trivial, in case of having virtual methods and more complex objects can introduce offset (it can be executed on uninitialized memory), and in case of virtual inheritance would cause SegFault - if B inherited A virtually and as implementation detail B contained pointer to A and allocated it dynamically).